# objective c syntax casting NSNumber to int

Tags: iphone, objective-c, optimization, memory-management, casting

In terms of memory and computation time, is it better to cast to an int value as:

```
int thisLetterInt = (int)[(NSNumber *)[levelSavedSolutionArrayFIX objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

or

```
int thisLetterInt = [[levelSavedSolutionArrayFIX objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

or is it exactly the same?

Also, I'm not responsible for releasing in either case right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The casts are unnecessary, you are just wasting hard disk space and CPU cycles during program compilation.

Even with ARC enabled, the compiler knows that for type `id` (which is what `-objectAtIndex:` returns), the most likely method signature for `-intValue` is `i@:` or, method returning an integer and taking 2 arguments (`self` and `_cmd`).

The only place where this would make a difference is if you were using dot-syntax, ex.

```
int thisLetterInt = [levelSavedSolutionArrayFIX objectAtIndex:i].intValue; // compile error
```

Because type `id` does not show any properties to the compiler, you must cast it first.

```
int thisLetterInt = ((NSNumber *)[levelSavedSolutionArrayFIX objectAtIndex:i]).intValue; // compiles fine
```

As far as releasing, no, primitive types are allocated on the stack, not the heap, which means they will be cleaned up automatically after the current scope is exited.

Comment: You're not wasting CPU cycles. Both will compile to the exact same thing. Or do you mean CPU cycles of the machine doing the compiling and having to read in some more characters in the source file?

Comment: @mattjgalloway yes, I meant compile time. clarified the post.

Comment: Good stuff. I think having the `NSNumber*` cast in there is a good idea still, though.

Comment: Nobody in this day and age should be worrying about 5 bytes of hard disk space (which in reality will end up being either 0 or 512, since files have to take up an integer number of sectors in pretty much every major file system in use).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield - Exactly. Also, the OP presumably meant runtime memory and computation time, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use the second approach. It's simpler and code is more readable.
In terms of memory management, you are not responsible for managing primitive types like int, float if you are not allocating memory for them using "new" operator like this `int *arr = new int[50];`.

Comment: `new` is a keyword reserved for C++. This question is about objc, not objc++. I believe you are talking about `malloc` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the most readable and safe way is to do this:

```
int thisLetterInt = [(NSNumber*)[levelSavedSolutionArrayFIX objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

Simply because `objectAtIndex` returns `id` and so you're then explicitly casting to an `NSNumber*` so the compiler will help you out if for instance you spelled `intValue` incorrectly, it would warn.

You don't need the cast to an `int` however, since `intValue` returns `int` so it is redundant.

In terms of memory and computation time - all these methods at runtime will be exactly the same. So there is no difference. The compiler will have to do slightly different jobs in each case but that will be so minuscule it's not worth worrying about.

And no releasing needs to be done, no.

Comment: Downvoted, because this isn't a question about style, but about `memory and computation time`.

Comment: But it really will make very very very little difference if any whatsoever. Please show us concrete proof if you think it does.

Comment: Also, added a bit about memory and computation time. I assumed he was talking about runtime memory and computation time.

Comment: True. Anyhow, what I really like to do with situations like this is to use ObjC++ and templates, so I have `vector<__strong NSNumber *> *myVector = new vector<__strong NSNumber *>();`. I don't know, I just like ObjC++.

Comment: Blimey. Not entirely sure why you would do that. The overhead of STL would annoy me a lot there. And all the subtleties of Obj-C++.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any casting so the second is correct. You just waste processor time. In any way you have to be sure that **levelSavedSolutionArrayFIX** contain NSNumber's elements. If it is possible to get another type in it - you get a crash. Any casting doesn't help you.

Comment: Unless of course that other type is like a NSString and responds to `-intValue` as well.

Comment: Any type that doesn't respond to intValue. NSString responds to intValue - so no problems.